# How is this import working without any relative path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

This is the directory I'm working in:

[image]

Now, `Auth.js` is importing a component from `components` like this:

```
import AuthNavbar from "components/Navbars/AuthNavbar.js";
```

Should'nt it be

```
import AuthNavbar from "../components/Navbars/AuthNavbar.js";
```

How is that import even working?

Comment: check your webpack configuration, it probably has a corresponding alias.

Comment: Your setup probably has a default alias for the `src` folder, which is letting you import in this way

Answer (score 0):

This might be working because your webpack configuration most likely has an alias.